# JavaScript Random number generator not working for numbers with double digit

Tags: javascript

I was working on a small project of generating a random number but there seems to be a problem.
The Generator works fine for single digit user input but not for double-digit.
For example,
if a user inputs 12 then the generator will generator will generate a password of 15 digits.
You can see the code on GitHub:
[GitHub](https://github.com/harshjangra12/JavaScript-Random-Password-Generator-)

JS CODE:

```
var results = document.getElementById("results");
var num;
var input;
var button = document.getElementById("gen");
var numb = "";

function getvalue(){
    input = document.getElementById("user").value;
    return input;
}

function randomNumber(upper){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*upper) + 1;
}

var nums = [];

button.addEventListener('click' , function() {
    if(!getvalue() || getvalue() == 0){
    results.innerHTML="<p>Your Have not entered any Value or Length<p>";
    }
    else{
    var counter = 0;
    while(counter<getvalue()){
        var num = randomNumber(getvalue());
        nums[counter] = num;
        counter += 1;       
    }
    numb = nums.join('');
    results.innerHTML="<p>Your Password is :<p>" + numb;
    numb = "";
    nums = [];
    }
});
```

Comment: A number only password is pretty unsecure, just saying...

Comment: Yeah, I know! I am new to js. I was just practicing. Any idea of a project I can work on to improve my basics.

Answer (score 0):

Your `randomNumber` function generates random numbers between 1 and its `upper` parameter, which currently comes from the user input (`randomNumber(getvalue());`) for some reason. So, if the user input is 10 or more, the random number generated can be 10 or more, resulting in a password string that has '10' in it where there should only be one number.

Generate random numbers between 0 and 9 instead:

```js
var results = document.getElementById("results");
var button = document.getElementById("gen");

function getvalue() {
  return document.getElementById("user").value;
}

function randomNumber(upper) {
  return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
}

button.addEventListener('click', function() {
  var nums = [];
  const value = getvalue();
  if (!value || value == 0) {
    results.innerHTML = "<p>Your Have not entered any Value or Length<p>";
    return;
  }
  var counter = 0;
  while (counter < value) {
    var num = randomNumber();
    nums[counter] = num;
    counter += 1;
  }
  const numb = nums.join('');
  results.innerHTML = "<p>Your Password is :<p>" + numb;
  console.log(numb.length);
});
```

```html
<div id="cont">
  <header>
    <h1>Generate Your Random Password</h1>
    <p class="one">This Application generates Random Password</p>
  </header>
  <section id="app">

    <p id="2">Enter Desired Length :)
      <p>
        <input type="number" id="user">
        <button id="gen">Generate</button>
        <div id="results">
          <p></p>
        </div>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining me. I really Appreciate that.